# Create new instance of std::thread/std::jthread on every read call

Tags: c++, stdthread

I am developing a serial port program using boost::asio.
In synchronous mode I create a thread every time read_sync function is called. All reading related operation are carried in this thread (implementation is in read_sync_impl function). 
On `close_port` or `stop_read` function reading operation is stopped. 
This stopped reading operation can be restarted by calling the `read_sync` function again. 
`read_sync` function will never be called successively without calling `close_port` or `stop_read`  function in between.

I wish to know how to implement a class wide `std::jthread` along with proper destructor when I call my read_sync function. In languages like Kotlin or Dart the garbage-collector takes care of this. What is C++ implementation of this.

```
bool SerialPort::read_sync(std::uint32_t read_length, std::int32_t read_timeout)
{
    this->thread_sync_read = std::jthread(&SerialPort::read_sync_impl, this);
    return true;
}

bool SerialPort::read_sync_impl(const std::stop_token& st)
{
    while(true)
    {
        ...
        if (st.stop_requested())
        {
            PLOG_INFO << "Stop Requested. Exiting thread.";
            break;
        }
    }
}

bool SerialPort::close_port(void)
{
    this->thread_sync_read->request_stop();
    this->thread_sync_read->join();
    this->port.close();
    return this->port.is_open();
}

class SerialPort
{
public :
    std::jthread *thread_sync_read = nullptr;
    ...
}
```

---

Actual Code

```
bool SerialPort::read_sync(std::uint32_t read_length, std::int32_t read_timeout)
{
    try
    {
        if (read_timeout not_eq ignore_read_timeout)
            this->read_timeout = read_timeout;//If read_timeout is not set to ignore_read_timeout, update the read_timeout else use old read_timeout
        if (this->thread_sync_read.joinable())
            return false; // Thread is already running
        thread_sync_read = std::jthread(&SerialPort::read_sync_impl, this);
        return true;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
        return false;
    }
}

void SerialPort::read_sync_impl(const std::stop_token& st)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (st.stop_requested())
            {
                PLOG_INFO << "Stop Requested in SerialPort::read_sync_impl. Exiting thread.";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        PLOG_ERROR << ex.what();
    }
}

class SerialPort
{
    std::jthread                    thread_sync_read;
    SerialPort() : io(), port(io), thread_sync_read()
    {
        read_buffer.fill(std::byte(0));
        write_buffer.fill(std::byte(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your program's intentions after joining to each thread, what will your program will do with the joined thread?

Comment: re: about garbage-collector: you do not declare the thread as (raw) pointer. and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: What do you mean by "class-wide"? From your code it looks like each ```SerialPort``` object gets its own thread. class-wide makes it sound like you want a single thread for the entire class, i.e. a static attribute

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am reading the serial port continuously in `while (true)`. During certain conditions I need to stop reading serial port and/or close the serial port. When such condition occur I destroy the reader thread while main thread continues to execute. When the next `read_sync` function is executed a new thread will be created.

Comment: This does not really answer the question: what does the program do with the joined thread. What is the purpose of using a joined thread, as opposed to a detached thread, which does not have any destruction, or post-termination formalities to take care of?

Comment: @Homer512 By `class-wide` I mean the thread object not get destroyed when `read_sync` function completes execute. It should remain valid till the `SerialPort` object is valid or will `close_port` method is not called. I don't want the thread to be static as number of `SerialPort` object vary from 1 to 5 depending on the configuration of the hardware and each `SerialPort` object will have its own independent thread.

Comment: @DarkSorrow it doesn't destroyed in your example.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The purpose of join is to wait till the `read_some` function has exited along with some book-keeping and only after this the port will be closed. It is for post-termination formalities to take care of. e.g. Avoid closing port while `read_some` function is executing and making sure few flags are cleared.

Comment: @appleapple That is what I am confused about. How to either manually destroy the `std::jthread` object or use a non-pointer object but reinitialize it with `read_sync_impl` on every read.

Comment: Ok, then everything is working as intended, so it's unclear what the question is here. But the updated explanation of what "class-wide" means suggests that the execution thread should not terminate, and should wait for the main execution thread to trigger whatever condition gets triggered that would normally start a new execution thread. This is a matter of implementing proper logic and thread synchronization, using mutexes and condition variables. However, if that were the case, "manually destroying" thread objects makes no sense. Your question, overall, is unclear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If  I join the thread how do I restart the thread afresh when I want?

Comment: Construct another thread object. Exactly the same way as the first execution thread.

Comment: (1) In most cases when using the asio library you don't need threads. Use async handlers instead, and you don't need to worry about concurrency. After all, asio = ASynchronous I/O. 
(2) There is standalone version of asio, if you just need serial ports and async I/O.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I am required to implement both synchronous and asynchronous functions as part of design specification.

Comment: @DarkSorrow that's fine asio provides both sync and async operations. I don't know anything about your requirements obviously, but I am can bet they can be handled without threads :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deal with the `jthread`'s destructor. A thread object constructed without constructor arguments (default constructor), or one that has been joined, is in an empty state. This can act as a stand-in for your `nullptr`.

```
class SerialPort
{
public :
    std::jthread thread_sync_read;
    ...

    SerialPort(...)
    : thread_sync_read() // no explicit constructor call needed, just for show
    {}
    SerialPort(SerialPort&&) = delete; // see side notes below
    SerialPort& operator=(SerialPort&&) = delete;

    ~SerialPort()
    {
        if(thread_sync_read.joinable())
            close_port();
    }
    bool read_sync(std::uint32_t read_length, std::int32_t read_timeout)
    {
        if(thread_sync_read.joinable())
            return false; // already reading
        /* start via lambda to work around parameter resolution
         * issues when using member function pointer
         */
        thread_sync_read = std::jthread(
          [this](const std::stop_token& st) mutable {
            return read_sync_impl(st);
          }
        );
        return true;
    }
    bool close_port()
    {
         thread_sync_read.request_stop();
         thread_sync_read.join(); // after this will be back in empty state
         port.close();
         return port.is_open();
    }
};
```

### Side notes

- Starting and stopping threads is rather expensive. Normally you would want to keep a single worker thread alive and feed it new read/write requests via a work queue or something like that. But there is nothing wrong with using a simpler design like yours, especially when starting and stopping are rare operations
- In the code above I delete the move constructor and assignment operator. The reason is that the thread captures the `this` pointer. Moving the `SerialPort` while the thread runs would lead to it accessing a dangling pointer

Comment: I am getting the mentioned error `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\include\thread(55,14): error C2672: 'invoke': no matching overloaded function found`. I have updated the question to include actual code.

Comment: @DarkSorrow There seems to be an issue with the resolution of the stop token argument and the this pointer. I fixed it by invoking the thread via a lambda

Comment: It worked. Can you direct me to the article where I can find more information about state of thread.

Comment: @DarkSorrow Here it is noted in the description and in the detailed description of ```join```: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread

Comment: @DarkSorrow BTW: You can expect similar behavior from most standard library types. To make move-construction work they have to have some sort of NULL state. At that point, they might as well make it available via default constructor and some form of ```is_valid()``` query

Comment: `st.stop_requested()` is returning true even if `request_stop()` method is not called. I have created a separate question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/73606423/6319901

Answer (score 1):

You're already reinitialize (move new one into) `thread_sync_read` in `SerialPort::read_sync`, everything should works.

---

at destructor, you need to remember delete `read_sync`

```cpp
SerialPort::~SerialPort(){
  close_port(); // if necessary to close port
  delete thread_sync_read;
}
```

---

or if you declare `thread_sync_read` not as (raw) pointer

```cpp
class SerialPort{
public:
    std::jthread thread_sync_read;
}
```

then you don't need to delete it.

```
SerialPort::~SerialPort(){
  close_port(); // if necessary
}
```

---

note that the destructor of `std::jthread` would perform necessary `request_stop()` and `join()` by itself.